# Different results from Python, R and SQL developer (Binomial test)

Tags: python, r, oracle-sqldeveloper

I run **binomial test with one sided probability and more (greater)** in Python, R and SQL Developer. And **p-value** from SQL Developer is different from Python and R.

```
       Python
            import scipy.stats as sc 
            sc.binom_test(x=12, n=20, p=0.4, alternative='greater')

       R
            aaa=binom.test (12, 20, 0.4, alternative = "greater")
            print(aaa$p.value,digits = 15)

       SQL Developer  
            with data1 as (select 1 as flag from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 1 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual
            union all   select 0 from dual )
STATS_BINOMIAL_TEST(flag, '1', 0.4, 'ONE_SIDED_PROB_OR_MORE') prob_or_less   FROM data1;
```

Results are following

```
Software   P-value             Difference from Python
Python     0.056526367034253   0
R          0.056526367034253   0.000000000000000
SQL        0.056526367018566   0.000000000015687
```

The difference is slight with small numbers, but has big impact in case of big input numbers. Could you please give me an advice where the problem in SQL Developer is? Thanks.

Comment: SQL Developer is just a java application using a jdbc driver to run that query against an Oracle Database - it doesn't calculate the output, it will format the output however.